# Saving data in Marklogic via Spark

Tags: apache-spark, marklogic

I'm trying to save a xml document in Marklogic from my Spark application.
 Currently I'm using 'MarkLogic Connector for Hadoop' (http://developer.marklogic.com/products/hadoop).
My requirement is..

Load data from Marklogic database.

Use spark to process the data (e.g. filtration, aggregation based on some criteria) and produce some form of xml\JSON which has the result.

Save the file (produced in step 2) into Marklogic.

For step 1, I was using 'Hadoop Connector', but it has no api to save data in Marklogic. 
So, I'm kind of stuck at this step. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Updated the question. Hope this clarifies any confusion. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use MarkLogic with the Hadoop libraries to load content into MarkLogic, then I think you'll need to look at how to [use MarkLogic as output for Hadoop](http://ttps://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/output).

Why not just use MarkLogic's [Java API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java) to handle the database connection, and then use Sparks forEachPartition to iterate over the items to return to MarkLogic as new documents using the Java API.

Note: I do not know Spark that well. However, I understand that the approach of forEachPartition vs forEach is used in other situations where an expensive operation needs to happen before iteration over nodes - such as a database connection.

Comment: Thanks David.. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can write a Hadoop code inside my Spark application and leverage RDD. 
I'm referring to this example which loads data in ML [ContentUploader]
(https://github.com/marklogic/HadoopExamples/blob/master/src/com/marklogic/mapreduce/examples/ContentLoader.java).

Comment: As David suggested, you could try MarkLogic's Java API instead of the hadoop connector.